# CSS customization doesn't work when uploaded to the server

Tags: html, css, ftp

My HTML page with CSS customization works well when previewed in a local computer using a browser but when I `FTP` it to my domain, CSS suddenly stops working. `Gradient` in the background, fonts and padding all get lost.


P.S. I have checked the link to my CSS in the HTML file and it rightly shows to be `./CSS/style.css`
Please help!

Comment: is it ./CSS/style.css or ../CSS/style.css

Comment: Use your browser developer tools to debug the issue.  Your console will tell you if the file is missing (404), and the HTML/CSS panels will help you debug what styles are being applied to each element.

Comment: i think correct syntax is ../

Answer (score 4):

include your css file properly `<link href="../CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` not `./CSS/style.css` provided your CSS folder is one level outside the html file to which you are including the same

Comment: Oh no! :( When I visit my domain via Safari on MAC OS X, things are fine. But again, some CSS goes missing when I visit via Chrome or Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check if the link itself is working - eg. Any styling is working at all.
If not, search for tutorials on how to link a css file into a html document - See link below
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

If the link is working, but those styles are not.

A. Selectors are wrong and elements are not being targeted properly

B. Elements styling is being overwritten somewhere else in the site. This site has a simple and easy to understand description of hierarchy in CSS and what gets applied over top of other styling
http://www.nzwhost.com/article/understanding-css-hierarchy

Ultimately, this is all speculation. I hope it solves your problem however without a look at the code itself, it could simply be a typo.

Comment: Oh no! :( When I visit my domain via Safari on MAC OS X, things are fine. But again, some CSS goes missing when I visit via Chrome or Firefox on Windows.

Comment: there is noting to go on for us, pls add more info or share your link